# Is 'should' a Tense?

Tags: syntax-trees, tense

I'm trying to write a syntax tree structure of a sentence with the word 'should'.  It's a long sentence, so to simply, let's take this sentence instead:

```
I should play the piano.
```

I'm not sure whether 'should' is the tense marker in the sentence.  To demonstrate (surface structure):

[image]

My argument is that in the sentence `I played the piano`, it's clear that the T has merged with the V....
Thanks!

Comment: Ask your teacher what they want you to call it; _should_ is only a tense marker if your teacher says it is. For everybody else, _should_ is a [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf), which, like all [modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html), is tenseless (though it is always [the first auxiliary](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) and thus should have tense if there were any) and takes an [infinitive complement with Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I have learnt, I wouldn't say that `should` **is** a tense, but I would say that it **carries** a past tense inflection. And about your idea of T merging with V, I would suggest considering the following. Basically, there is a hypothesis saying that TPs are headed by a T constituent, either overt or null. Merging occurs, but that wouldn't fully explain what happens to T. In your fist example, the head of T is the modal auxiliary verb, but in the finite clause, the T would have a null phonetic spell out of a tense affix which also carries person and number features. The idea is that heads cannot be empty, and in this case the tense affix undergoes a morphological operation called **affix hopping**.  Thus, in the sentence `I played the piano`, the T head would be something like `Tense-3SgPr` and it would be lowered onto the head V `play`. The derived structure would be `[play+Affix-3SgPr]`, which in turn would be spelled out as `played`. See Radford (2006) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Surely "I should play piano" carries a *future* tense inflection? "I should *have* *played* the piano" would be past tense, no?